# Integrating Firebase-Admin with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, firebase, aurelia, fs, firebase-admin

In trying to implement firebase-admin in my aurelia project, I've ran into some issues, I was wondering if someone could try to help me out.

I first installed firebase-admin through the console with:

```
npm install --save firebase-admin
```

Then on main.js, I imported it as admin and declared the serviceAccount.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
serviceAccount: './serviceAccountKey.json';
```

On the same page, inside export funciont configure(aurelia) I put this:

```
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: './serviceAccountKey.json',
    databaseURL: 'https://contactmanager-be4d3.firebaseio.com'
  });
```

I also made sure to reference firebase-admin on the aurelia.json file:

```
  {
    "name": "firebase-admin",
    "path": "../node_modules/firebase-admin/lib",
    "main": "index"
  },
```

But when running, I get this error:

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\vasco.bento\chapter-3\app\src\fs.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.exports.readFileSync (C:\Users\vasco.bento\chapter-3\app\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\file-system.js:49:13)
    at fileRead (C:\Users\vasco.bento\chapter-3\app\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\bundled-source.js:83:31)
    at Object.context.fileRead (C:\Users\vasco.bento\chapter-3\app\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:176:18)
    at Object.context.load (C:\Users\vasco.bento\chapter-3\app\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:357:30)
    at Module.load (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\vasco.bento\chapter-3\app\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:832:29)
    at Module.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\vasco.bento\chapter-3\app\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:822:66)
    at Module.check (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\vasco.bento\chapter-3\app\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:854:30)
    at Module.enable (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\vasco.bento\chapter-3\app\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\amodro-trace\lib\loader\Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:1173:22)
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\vasco.bento\\chapter-3\\app\\src\\fs.js',
  moduleTree: [ 'firebase-admin/firebase-namespace' ],
  fileName: 'C:/Users/vasco.bento/chapter-3/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js' }
```

Which makes sense, given fs isn't inside the lib folder, or any folder inside node_modules/firebase-admin.

[firebase-admin folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRMiB.png)

I was wondering how I could be able to solve this issue, and the best way to set up firebase-admin with Aurelia.

Comment: Is this a client-side app framework? If so you can't use Admin SDK with it.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I wonder how I would call the functions from my API with Aurelia though.

Comment: Typically how this goes down is you run a server app somewhere. You can use your own server or an environment like Google Cloud Functions for this. Then your client app calls the server app via REST/JSON.